# Word that means "a professional person"

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider the following sentence.

> The TA would communicate with the students through email, but keep in mind that he still had to maintain a professional *what?*

Figure, identity, boundary?

Basically, even though we communicate through email, we still must be professional in our emails, and so I am looking what that word.

Comment: _Proefessional_ is a noun that can mean _a professional person_ as well.

Comment: It looks like your title question is asking for one thing - a *professional person* is usually called a *professional* - but your sentence-with-a-blank is asking another - perhaps, *distance*, or *detachment*?

Comment: @KSplitX are you suggesting that communication by email is somehow disreputable? How is the medium relevant?

Comment: @WeatherVane no. I mean in email, among students personally, they tend to use "slang" language, not saying hello, etc. thats what i mean but staying professional. Talking in a professional manner

Comment: How about ***demeanor***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think *demeanor* may be the word you're looking for:

[dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/demeanor?s=t):

> conduct; behavior; deportment.

[oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demeanour):

> Outward behaviour or bearing.

Comment: This was the word I was looking for! I had it on the tip of my tongue but couldn't quite get it. THANK YOU!